# Embed foreign urls with Laravel using embedly or others

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, embedly

I want to create an app where users can share links from foreign websites and a thumbnail/image appear with a little description under it (something like facebook, twitter, reddit..). So I tried to use **embedly** in my **laravel project**
I to install embedly in my laravel using the badawy/embedly package but it doesn't seem to work.
The error that I get is

```
Class 'Badawy\Embedly\EmbedlyServiceProvider' not found.
```

Does anybody have any suggestion about how to solve the problem or other ways to embed foreign links to my website?

Answer (score 1):

Add the service provider to the providers array in your config/app.php file: Badawy\Embedly\EmbedlyServiceProvider::class, Add the facade to your config/app.php file: 'Embedly' => Badawy\Embedly\Facades\Embedly::class . It's info from documentation.